# users followin the blog post author

Tags: posts, multisite, author

I have a code which is supposed to follow the author of blog post but whenever the follow button is typed it gets an critical error on the wordpress.
heres the script

```
<?php 
// Get current user
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Get current user ID
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

// Get ID of post author
$post_author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

// Check if current user is following post author
$is_following = in_array( $post_author_id, get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'following', true ) );

// Follow button
if ( !$is_following && $current_user_id != $post_author_id ) {
    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_author_id" value="' . $post_author_id . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
    echo '</form>';
}

// Unfollow button
if ( $is_following ) {
    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_author_id" value="' . $post_author_id . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="unfollow" value="Unfollow">';
    echo '</form>';
}

// Follow post author
if ( isset( $_POST['follow'] ) ) {
    $following = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'following', true );
    $following[] = $_POST['post_author_id'];
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'following', $following );

    // Add current user to post author's followers list
    $followers = get_user_meta( $_POST['post_author_id'], 'followers', true );
    $followers[] = $current_user_id;
    update_user_meta( $_POST['post_author_id'], 'followers', $followers );
}

// Unfollow post author
if ( isset( $_POST['unfollow'] ) ) {
    $following = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'following', true );
    $following = array_diff( $following, array( $_POST['post_author_id'] ) );
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'following', $following );

    // Remove current user from post author's followers list
    $followers = get_user_meta( $_POST['post_author_id'], 'followers', true );
    $followers = array_diff( $followers, array( $current_user_id ) );
    update_user_meta( $_POST['post_author_id'], 'followers', $followers );
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: "There has been a critical error on this website."